# Reference request: Ito formula for function $G(t, x)$ when $G$ depend on $\omega$

Tags: reference-request, stochastic-calculus

There is proved Lemma in book : Let the function $G(t,x)$ is defined when $t\in [0,T], x\in(-\infty,\infty)$, $G$ has continuous derivative with respect to $t$ and twice continuously diferentiable with respect to $x$. Then $$dG(t,w(t))=[G'_t(t,w(t))+1/2G''_{xx}(t,w(t))]+G'_x(t,w(t))dw(t).$$
Here $w(t)$ is brownian motion.
After that without proof there is Claim, that Lemma is true if $G(t,x)$ depend on $\omega$ , $G(t,w(t))$ is measurable with respect to $\sigma$-algebra $F_t$ and for each $\omega$ conditions of the lemma are satisfied. 
My question: How to prove this Claim? Could you provide reference to concise proof of it?

Comment: Could you provide the book your question is about?

Comment: This book is Stochastic Differential Equations, Authors: Gihman, Iosif I., Skorohod, Anatolij V. I have only russian edition of this book.